# Pandas dataframe, filtering out values over a value from groupby

Tags: pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

I have a lengthy CSV, covering several days, with data every 5 seconds, from multiple channels that are repeated over the 5 seconds period. The format is similar to this:

```
IoT Channel    Datetime                 [ Other fields ]         calculated_value
Chan1          01/01/2020 01:00:00      [...]                    1.50203
Chan2          01/01/2020 01:00:00      [...]                    0.80203
Chan3          01/01/2020 01:00:00      [...]                    4.23232
...
ChanN          01/01/2020 01:00:00      [...]                    2.32123
Chan1          01/01/2020 01:00:05      [...]                    1.23232
Chan2          01/01/2020 01:00:05      [...]                    0.23234
Chan3          01/01/2020 01:00:05      [...]                    3.12312
...
ChanN          01/01/2020 01:00:05      [...]                    5.12321
Chan1          01/01/2020 01:00:10      [...]                    1.12312
Chan2          01/01/2020 01:00:10      [...]                    0.99232
Chan3          01/01/2020 01:00:10      [...]                    5.23323
...
ChanN          01/01/2020 01:00:10      [...]                    2.00012
Chan1          01/01/2020 01:00:15      [...]                    1.55552
Chan2          01/01/2020 01:00:15      [...]                    0.77874
Chan3          01/01/2020 01:00:15      [...]                    4.23232
...
ChanN          01/01/2020 01:00:15      [...]                    2.32123
```

Issue is, we have some peak values that are messing up the analysis as they are several orders bigger than average, affecting calculations and charts.

I'd like to get the average value for each channel, and then filter out the values going twice the average. That seems to work to filter out the peaks we have.

However, I can't figure out how to do this, my knowledge on pandas is not that big. I can filter the whole dataframe over a single values, but I understand I need to filter the values per channel based on its avg * 2. How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

You can make a new column with the mean per group

```
df = df.join(df.groupby('IoT Channel')['calculated_value'].mean(), on='IoT Channel', rsuffix='_mean')
```

and filter the peak values that are 2 times larger than `calculated_value_mean`.

```
df_new = df.drop(df[(df['calculated_value'] > (2 * df['calculated_value_mean']))].index)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I will approach it:

```
from io import StringIO


df = pd.read_csv(StringIO("""IoT_Channel,Datetime,calculated_value
Chan1   ,       01/01/2020 01:00:00   ,  1.50203
Chan2   ,       01/01/2020 01:00:00   ,  0.80203
Chan3   ,       01/01/2020 01:00:00   ,  4.23232
ChanN   ,       01/01/2020 01:00:00   ,  2.32123
Chan1   ,       01/01/2020 01:00:05   ,  1.23232
Chan2   ,       01/01/2020 01:00:05   ,  0.23234
Chan3   ,       01/01/2020 01:00:05   ,  3.12312
ChanN   ,       01/01/2020 01:00:05   ,  5.12321
Chan1   ,       01/01/2020 01:00:10   ,  1.12312
Chan2   ,       01/01/2020 01:00:10   ,  0.99232
Chan3   ,       01/01/2020 01:00:10   ,  5.23323
ChanN   ,       01/01/2020 01:00:10   ,  2.00012
Chan1   ,       01/01/2020 01:00:15   ,  1.55552
Chan2   ,       01/01/2020 01:00:15   ,  0.77874
Chan3   ,       01/01/2020 01:00:15   ,  4.23232
ChanN   ,       01/01/2020 01:00:15   ,  2.32123"""))


df_median = df.groupby("IoT_Channel")['calculated_value'].median()
# merge median values
df = df.merge(df_median, left_on='IoT_Channel', right_index=True)
# filter 
df = df[df.calculated_value_x < 2*df.calculated_value_y]
#drop added cols and rename them
del df["calculated_value_x"]
df.rename(columns={'calculated_value_y':'calculated_value'}, inplace=True)
```

This will drop the values which are larger than twice the median. Use of median will be better than mean.